# How to stop Task running terminal to exit automatically after the program ends in visual studio code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am a new c++ learner and using visual studio code as my IDE. As an example, a cpp file has the hello world program written in it. In VSC, I compile the cpp file with a task named `Build`( >Tasks: Run Build task), and run it using the task named `Run`( >Tasks: Run task). (tasks.json is given below)

But when I `Run`, a new terminal named "Task - Run" starts, shows the output and immediately exits.(Its very hard to see what was the output.)

Is there any command that I can put into the tasks.json file so that the program doesn't disappear after it ends? Or is there any other workaround?

```
//my tasks.json file

{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "Build",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "g++",
        "args": [
            "main.cpp"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "problemMatcher": []
    },
    {
        "taskName": "Run",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "./a.out",
        "problemMatcher": []
    }
]
}
```

Comment: One workaround is to try and read a new line at the end of the application so that it will wait for user input. Then, it will exit when you press enter (because of the `\n` character).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response but, I don't want to change the source code. "Hello world" in the description was just an example. I sometimes participate in competitive programming and there, I can't add a new line reader at the end of my code(As that would result TLE in all OJ). There are also more reasons not to change the source code.

Comment: I see. Then that's indeed problematic. Another way you could try this would be to intercept the SIGTERM signal and somehow prevent the terminal from closing, but that also means modifying the source code (quite a lot actually). If this still doesn't meet your needs, then I think the only thing left to do is to search the IDE or the `tasks.json` file for some kind of setting.

Comment: Yes, actually I AM searching for it. But can't find one. That's why I posted here :). Also for now, I am just manually making a makefile and running it in the terminal of VSC. But it is painful to do like this instead of running the program with just a short-cut key.

Answer (score 0):

More of a hack than a fix but I have the same issue and I noticed that changing the version from "2.0.0" to "0.1.0" would keep my output window open with all the errors present.

Though I'm quite sure that this is not a long term solution.

Comment: Doesn't work. It gives the following error: "Value is not accepted. Valid values: ["2.0.0"]". Also When I run a task. Nothing happens. I think it is version specific. That means it may work on your VSC, but not mine.

Comment: @RahatZaman I'm using VSC Version 1.15.1. I also get the the error "Value is not accepted" but I can ignore it and run the task without issues.

Comment: We are using same version then. But as said before, nothing happens when I run a task.